# Dirichlet problem in upper half space

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Consider
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
- \Delta u & = & 0, \ \ \mbox{in} \ \mathbb{R}^2_+\\
u(x,0) & = & e^{-\pi x^2}, \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{array} \right.$$
Show that
$$\max \{u(x, y); \ (x, y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]\} = 1.$$

**Outline of the proof:** To solve this problem, I tried to use the fact that if $u$ is the solution to the problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
- \Delta u & = & 0, \ \ \mbox{in} \ \mathbb{R}^2_+\\
u & = & g, \ \ \mbox{on} \ \partial \mathbb{R}^2_+,
\end{array} \right.$$
we have
$$u (x_1, x_2) = \dfrac{2x_2}{2\omega_2} \int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^2_+} \dfrac{g(y)}{|x-y|^2} dy,$$
with $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 _+$ and $y \in \partial \mathbb{R}^2_+$. However, I was confused on how to solve this integral under the given conditions... Help me, I have difficulty in this type of solution!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What on earth does "What max(...)=1." mean?

Comment: I improved the notation. See if you can understand!

Comment: Yes, now it's clear!

Comment: This is not true. Since $\mathbb R^2_+$ is unbounded you don't have uniqueness. Indeed, if $u$ solves your problem and $\max_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}u=1$ then $v_M = u + M y$ also solves your problem for all $M>0$. But $\max_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}v_M =M$ for large enough $M$ so you can make this max arbitrarily large.

Comment: Now if you had some decay assumption on $u$ or you were specifically interested in the Poisson representation then things would be different